# Scala & Spark : java.lang.ArrayStoreException on deserialisation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, json4s

I'm working on in Scala & Spark to load a big file (60+ GB) JSON file and process it. Since using sparksession.read.json leads to out-of-memory exception, I've went to the RDD route.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.{read}

val submissions_rdd  = sc.textFile("/home/user/repos/concepts/abcde/RS_2019-09")
//val columns_subset = Set("author", "title", "selftext", "score", "created_utc", "subreddit")

case class entry(title: String, 
                 selftext: String, 
                 score: Double, 
                 created_utc: Double, 
                 subreddit: String, 
                 author: String)


def jsonExtractObject(jsonStr: String) = {
  implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

  read[entry](jsonStr)

}
```

Upon testing my function on a single entry, I get the desired result:

```
val res = jsonExtractObject(submissions_rdd.take(1)(0))
```

> ```
> res: entry =
> entry(Last Ditch Effort,&amp;#x200B;
>
> https://preview.redd.it/9x4ld036ivj31.jpg?width=780&amp;format=pjpg&amp;auto=webp&amp;s=acaed6cc0d913ec31b54235ca8bb73971bcfe598,1.0,1.567296E9,YellowOnlineUnion,Sgedelta)
> ```

Problem is, after trying to map the same function to the RDD I'm getting an error:

```
val subset = submissions_rdd.map(line => jsonExtractObject(line) )
subset.take(5)
```

> org.apache.spark.SparkDriverExecutionException: Execution error   at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1485)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2236)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)   at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2120)   at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2139)   at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$take$1(RDD.scala:1423)   at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)   at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1396)   ... 41 elided Caused
> by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: [Lentry;   at
> scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.array_update(ScalaRunTime.scala:75)   at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$4(SparkContext.scala:2120)
> at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$4$adapted(SparkContext.scala:2120)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.JobWaiter.taskSucceeded(JobWaiter.scala:59)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1481)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2236)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)

Would appreciate if any has any hints on how to go around that. Thanks!

Comment: Thank @AndriyPlokhotnyuk, but I'm hitting a NotSerializableException now.


`implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[entry] = JsonCodecMaker.make
val subset = submissions_rdd.map(line => readFromArray(line.getBytes("UTF-8")) )
`

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: $anon$1

Comment: I've ended up using sparksession.read.json  but with a explicitly defined schema (was using implicit before). Thanks!